How to upload file with Uri in Android
In my application I want use this library for record the screen : https://github.com/HBiSoft/HBRecorder 
After record the screen I should upload this video to server. 
I write below codes, but when read Uri file and upload to server show me error! 
Activity codes: 
lifecycleScope.launch {
            delay(250)
            fileUri = if (SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.Q) FILE_URI else FILE_PATH?.convertFileToUri()
            Log.e("filePathUri","FileUri $fileUri")
            uploadVideo(fileUri!!)
        }

    private fun uploadVideo(uri: Uri) {
        val file = getFileFromContentUri5(this, uri)
        val bodyBuilder = MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
        Log.e("filePathUri","File path ${file?.path}")
        bodyBuilder.addFormDataPart("file", file?.name, file!!.asRequestBody("video/*".toMediaTypeOrNull()))
        val requestBody = bodyBuilder.build()
        val requestBodyWithProgress = RequestBodyWithProgress(requestBody) { progress ->
            runOnUiThread {
                binding.apply {
                    uploadProgress.progress = progress
                    uploadPercentageTxt.text = "$progress%"
                }
            }
        }
        //Call api
        viewModel.callPostUploadVideo(testId, requestBodyWithProgress)
    }

fun getFileFromContentUri5(context: Context, contentUri: Uri): File? {
    val contentResolver = context.contentResolver
    val file = File(context.cacheDir, "temp_video.mp4")

    try {
        contentResolver.openInputStream(contentUri)?.use { inputStream ->
            FileOutputStream(file).use { outputStream ->
                inputStream.copyTo(outputStream)
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return null
    }

    if (file.length() > 0) {
        return file
    } else {
        Log.e("Error", "File is empty after copying from URI")
        return null
    }
}

Show me this logs for file in logcat : 
FileUri content://media/external/video/media/1000023197
File path null

And show this error and crashed the app : 
Process: com.myapp, PID: 26203
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.myapp.ui.compress_upload.CompressUploadActivity.uploadVideo(CompressUploadActivity.kt:193)
    at com.myapp.ui.compress_upload.CompressUploadActivity.access$uploadVideo(CompressUploadActivity.kt:53)
    at com.myapp.ui.compress_upload.CompressUploadActivity$onCreate$2.invokeSuspend(CompressUploadActivity.kt:116)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.resume(DispatchedTask.kt:234)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.dispatch(DispatchedTask.kt:166)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.dispatchResume(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:397)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:431)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl$default(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:420)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeUndispatched(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:518)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.android.HandlerContext$scheduleResumeAfterDelay$$inlined$Runnable$1.run(Runnable.kt:19)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:9063)

                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:588)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
    Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@d518d27, Dispatchers.Main.immediate]

I know this error fo NullPointerExeption! but I want know why show me null path and how can I fix it?

which line of code you shared is CompressUploadActivity.kt: line 193?

btw you shouldn't do this file!! because your method can return null, so that'll crash. You need to handle not having a file.

@Blundell , show me error for this line : bodyBuilder.addFormDataPart("file", file?.name, file!!.asRequestBody("video/*".toMediaTypeOrNull()))

Looks like getFileFromContentUri5 is going into the catch block and returning null or your file length is 0 and so returning null. You need to work out which it is.

@Blundell why can not create file from Uri? how can I create file from Uri? can you send to me code? thank you
